# Conection Azure Databricks - VBA

Tags: vba, database, azure-databricks

Anyone know if it's possible to connect and manipulate the database in a cluster in Azure Databricks by the command ADODB in VBA?

I want to Insert new values in a table in my database as they are inserted in the worsheet.

I know that I can do this using SQL Server, but haven't found a way using Databricks.

In SQL Server, I 'd something like this to start with:

```
'''Sub DBRegister()


Dim MDB             As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS              As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim FD              As ADODB.Field
Dim SQL             As String

Dim w               As Worksheet


MDB.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx.xx.200.168;UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxx"
```

'''

Comment: You should be able to connect.  This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/connect-databricks-excel-python-r) will get you started.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to point out that you should use backticks ``` to format your code, not apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the DSN established as posted above this code should create the connection and allow to query for a recordset.

```
 Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 cn.Open "DSN=DSNNAMEHERE;UID=token;Password=ACCESSTOKENHERE" 
 rs.open "SELECT * From TableName"
```